# temperature conversion for python

Tags: python, python-3.x, decimal, floating-point-precision

I'm taking a free online Python tutorial, which wants me to:

> Create a temperature converter which will convert Fahrenheit values to
>   Celsius and vice-versa using the following two formulas which relate
>   the temperature f in Fahrenheit to the temperature c in Celsius:
>
> ```
>     f = c *  9/5 + 32
>     c = (f -32)* 5/9
> ```
>
> The input will be a string consisting of a floating-point number followed immediately by the letter `F` or `C`, such
>   as `"13.2C"`. I need to convert to the other temperature scale and print
>   the converted value in the same format. For example, if the input is
>   "8F" then the output should be (approximately) `"-13.333C"`, and if the
>   input is `"12.5C"` then the output should be `"54.5F"`.

My answers are always slightly off.  For example I get `-16.444444444444446C` when the correct output is `-16.394444444444442C`.  Is there a problem with how I am using float? My code is as follows:

```
def celsiusCon(farenheit):
   return (farenheit - 32)*(5/9)
def farenheitCon(celsius):
   return ((celsius*(9/5)) + 32)

inputStr = input()
inputDig = float(inputStr[0:-2])
if inputStr[-1] == 'C':
   celsius = inputDig
   print(farenheitCon(celsius),'F',sep ='')
if inputStr[-1] == 'F':
   farenheit = inputDig
   print(celsiusCon(farenheit),'C', sep='')
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are cutting off the last *two* characters, not just the last one:

```
inputDig = float(inputStr[0:-2])
```

should be:

```
inputDig = float(inputStr[0:-1])
```

This accounts for your accuracy problem:

```
>>> celsiusCon(2.4)
-16.444444444444446
>>> celsiusCon(2.49)
-16.394444444444446
```

Since slicing counts from the end, slicing to `:-2` cuts of both the unit and the last digit:

```
>>> '2.49F'[:-2]
'2.4'
>>> '2.49F'[:-1]
'2.49'
```

Answer (score 0):

notice your code is too long,instead of that:

```
tempInit = input()
temp = float(tempInit[:-1])
if tempInit[-1]== 'F':
    c=(temp-32)*5/9
    print(str(c)+'C')
if tempInit[-1]== 'C':
    f =(temp*9/5)+32
    print(str(f)+'F')
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick and dirty method.

```
temp = float(input("What's the temperature? C > F")))

conversion = (temp*9/5)+32

print(conversion)
```

This will convert from C > F, you can easily flip this around.